# resizing default android tab issue

Tags: android, tabs, dimensions

I want to change the size of the android tabs, but I don't want to make all new drawables for them. The tabs will just have text, no icons, and will be part of a workspace view that responds to horizontal flings, so having a full tab is not necessary for me. But I still want them default drawables for the purpose of trackball navigation or in case the user wants to press to jump to a tab without using the workspace fling.

My code is basically this

```
    height = (int) (height * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabWidget.getChildCount(); i++) {
        tabWidget.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = height;
    }

    tabWidget.getLayoutParams().height = height;
```

The problem I am running into is that the tabs have an unexpected appearance based on the height. If I set the height to anything less than 60, there is a gradient that appears, and only goes about 30dip up vertically. If I set it to 60 or above, the gradient goes all the way up.

I attached a picture to illustrate. Top examples have the bottom tabs set to 30 dip, bottom to 40 dip. In each example, the top set of tabs is >= 60.

[image]

Anyone know how I can either get rid of the gradient or force it to cover the whole vertical area?

Update:

Tried the exact tab resize code on the hello tab widget demo, and same issue. Which tells me I am failing to do something in my resizing if this strategy has worked for somebody else

[image: from api demo]

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide the icon view:

```
tabWidget.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.icon).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: tried it earlier, no change, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: It's strange. Because I use the similar code in my app without a glitch. Maybe your issue is related to a particular layout you're using.

Comment: thats encouraging. I will keep playing around and see if something else is causing it.

Comment: it has to be something that I am not doing if it works for you, can you check what I wrote above? Maybe you can post your function that works? thanks

Comment: My apologizes. I've experimented with my code trying different heights and caught the same issue with gradient. I've looked in android sources and found that the background of tab is just 9-patch image, which is relatively high (98 pixels in height). So, it looks like image downscaling problem (side effects).

Comment: That was the theory I came up with too. Too bad.